# Why does Visual Studio fail to set a conditional breakpoint on this simple C# property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In my C# object, I set a conditional breakpoint with the condition `value == "Status"` in the setter of this property. Normally it's decorated with a PostSharp aspect, but I've commented that out in this case, and it's still having trouble.

```
public virtual string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value; // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

The first time execution reaches the breakpoint, VS displays an error:

[image: Visual Studio MessageBox]

EDIT - for searchability, the message is this:

> The following breakpoint cannot be set:
>
> At (file).cs, line 137 character 17 ('(class).Name', line 12), when 'value == "Status"' is true
>
> The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

Here's what the Threads window looks like:

[image: Debugger Threads window]

Anyone seen this before, or have any ideas what might be causing the debugger to baulk at this seemingly-simple case? Might it have something to do with the sleeping thread?

Comment: This links can be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ecfxd9.aspx , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/11/18/494648.aspx

Comment: In my efforts to devise a workaround, I've found that it's *at least sometimes* possible to simply disable the breakpoint, run (`F5`) and immediately re-enable the breakpoint. I'd hazard a guess that the threading message isn't the red herring I had assumed it to be, although the actual cause still eludes me... 

Of course, the fact that the debugger needs any thread other than the current one to be active in order to evaluate a parameter value makes equally little sense to me. That said, I've never written a debugger :)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Good links, but I'm still at a loss as to why evaluating `value` (which is a parameter, which I would certainly hope isn't a func eval) and equating it to a string literal would do anything that requires another thread

Comment: I guess it's a bug in debugger :) Maybe MSFT VS 2010 debugger team knows this and punted this for next release :P

Comment: I can't reproduce this based on the code that you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually devised a workaround:

```
public virtual string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == "Status")
            DoSomeNoOp(); // Breakpoint here, or Debug.Fail() inside your no-op

        _name = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I once had this problem when I encountered a situation when it goes out of the execution of the base thread. A bit more information on the flow of your application will help. It seems to me like a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it knows what `value` is. Try to put the breakpoint on the closing `}` and use `_name` in the condition.

Comment: `value` isn't the problem; I've used that symbol in other conditions and it has worked fine.